# Remove server from pgAdmin4 server list

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In pgAdmin4, I'm trying to delete "PostgreSQL 15" from my server list since I installed V16 and removed all V15 files. (Windows 11, PostgreSQL V16, pgAdmin v7.8)

I can "Remove" the server from the server list in pgAdmin4 but restarting pgAdmin4, it comes back into the list. I don't have any files on my system for V15. Somehow the pdAdmin4 config simply will not blow that server away. Even after I totally deleted all V15 files, deleted the process from the services and restarted my system.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: After you delte and it comes back, what is the 'comments' for the server when you open 'properies' for it?

Comment: Auto-detected PostgreSQL 15 installation with the data directory at C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\data  This folder does not exist on my system.

Comment: Again, this folder (or any other data related to V15 has been deleted and does not exist on my system. There must be a configuration file somewhere that has this  file folder in it but I searched everywhere and cannot find any reference to that specific folder. So it appears pgAdmin is interrogating something else on my system to make the decision that the V15 server is still running.

Comment: Do you have OneDrive running?  (It seems to turn itself on uninvited).  I have been seeing a lot of issues lately, not specifically with PgAdmin, where previously existing files randomly claim to still exist depending on which program asks for them, the phase of the moon, and what Satya Nadella had for breakfast.

Comment: No, I don't have OneDrive installed on my system. By the way, this is happening on other systems as well. I just installed V16 from another person's system and they had both V10 and V14 installed at one time. Their pgAdmin will not retain the deletion of the V10 or V14 servers. Same symptoms. Delete doesn't stay deleted.

Comment: @Rick were you able to solve this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No. The bug prevails.

Comment: Aparen5ly this problem has been resolved, I suspect with the last version of pfAdmin.